# Why is VsPerfAspNetCmd throwing the error "Value does not fall within the expected range"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am trying to profile an ASP.NET application  the Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET profiler and I get the following output:

```
C:\MyWebApp>VSPerfAspNetCmd /i /Output:MyWebAppSampling.vsp http://localhost/MyWebApp
Microsoft (R) VSPerf ASP.NET Command, Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Configuring and attaching to ASP.NET process. Please wait.
Setting up profiling environment.
Starting monitor.

Error
VSP 1001: Unhandled exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

I cannot find any documentation on MSDN or results on the web that indicate why this error may be occurring. Here are any parameters that may also be relevant:

- My workstation hosting the web application is Windows XP
- The web application is using .NET Framework 3.5
- The web application (and referenced projects) are compiled in Release|Any CPU mode

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I finally got around to testing ASP.NET Profiling in a server environment (Windows Server 2003 Standard SP2) and profiling does function. The website runs on the server at http://localhost:9001, whereas the website runs on my workstation at http://localhost/MyWebApp, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

VSPerfAspNetCmd requires several IIS 6 features. Are you running IIS 6 on your Windows XP machine? You might also want to check that the features described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/colinth/archive/2010/07/23/tip-fixing-vsperfaspnetcmd-metabase-errors.aspx) are enabled.

Comment: Yes, Windows XP always runs IIS 6 I believe. The article you referenced deals with enabling IIS 6 features *when running on Windows 7*. I can't enable "IIS 6 Management Console" specifically on Windows XP because there's no other management console that is enabled by default.

Comment: Right, I was talking more about the optional features listed at the end of the article: IIS 6 Scripting Tools, IIS 6 WMI Compatibility, IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility, ASP.NET, Windows Authentication.

They likely have slightly different names in IIS 6.